# codeigniter: how to resize after cropping

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

So I’m cropping an image I’m uploading with the following code (successfully):

```
    $file_name = $this->input->post('file_name');
    $x1 = $this->input->post('x1');
    $y1 = $this->input->post('y1');
    $x2 = $this->input->post('x2');
    $y2 = $this->input->post('y2');

    //die('width: '.$width.' height: '.$height.' id: '.$id.' file_name: '.$file_name.' x1: '.$x1.' x2: '.$x2.' y1: '.$y1.' y2: '.$y2.' w: '.$w.' h: '.$h);

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']    = './images/uploads/temp/'.$file_name;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = $y2;
    $config['height'] = $y2;
    $config['x_axis'] = $x1;
    $config['y_axis'] = $y1;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

And at this point I want to resize the image as I have just gotten the selection and ratio I want and am not sure how to do this. Here’s what I assumed would work immediately afterward in the same method:

```
    $config['width'] = 180;
    $config['height'] = 180;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize() )
    {
        die( $this->image_lib->display_errors() ); //
    }
```

It doesn’t give any errors or anything, it just doesn’t resize the image. Can you please help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as if the second time you load the library (thus initializing it again) it doesn't receive all the params it needs. Are you using the code in the same method, or in another?
Anyway, if inside the same method, **as a test** try doubling some configs after clearing them:

```
//
//CROPPING HERE....Then:
//

$this->image_lib->clear();

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image']    = './images/uploads/temp/'.$file_name;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 180;
$config['height'] = 180;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

And be sure to have the folder and files with correct permissions.

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!!! You are my hero! The cropping is a tiny bit off, but I can fiddle with that.